# c++ trivial try-catch causes abort

Tags: c++

the simple code  below

```
// g++ centro.cc -o centro

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try
    {
        cout << "Going to throw" << endl;
        throw;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "An exception occurred" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

produces an abort:

```
Going to throw
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't understand what's wrong, can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your line

```
throw;
```

is the syntax for re-throwing an exception in a `catch` block.

You should write:

```
throw std::exception();
```

Answer (score 8):

Try thowing *something*. You aren't throwing any exception.

`throw;` itself is generally used to re-throw the same exception inside a `catch` block.

Compare the result with `throw "something";` or perhaps an instance of `std::exception`.

Answer (score 3):

This is mandated by the standard (15.1):

> 8) A throw-expression with no operand rethrows the currently handled
>   exception (15.3). The exception is reactivated with the existing
>   temporary; no new temporary exception object is created. The exception
>   is no longer considered to be caught; therefore, the value of
>   std::uncaught_exception() will again be true.
>
> 9) If no
>   exception is presently being handled, executing a throw-expression
>   with no operand calls std:: terminate() (15.5.1).

Answer (score 2):

`throw;` on its own rethrows the exception that is currently being processed, but there isn't one in your code.

You need to throw something. Try something like `throw std::runtime_error("my message");` instead. You'll need to include `#include <stdexcept>` for this.

In real code you'll want to create your own exception class to throw most likely